# Listbox values from webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, api, data-binding

In my ASP.NET WebApp write in C#, i Have a form for user registration. I want retrieve values from webservice([This url](https://api.christiangiupponi.it/)), and popolate the ListBox in my form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different ways of doing it assuming your web service is returning JSON format => http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/07/how-to-bind-dropdownlist-in-aspnet.html